# Haskell: Get String representation/Pattern Match without evaluating the Integer

Tags: haskell

I have a function `func` that takes an `Integer`. How can I identify whether the Integer passed to `func` is made up of `^`? I don't want to evaluate the Integer if it is made up of large number, say 200^350. Here is a pseudo Haskell code:

```
func :: Integer -> Integer
func x = case x of (a ^ b) -> func1 a b
                   otherwise -> func2 x
```

`func` may be called as `func (200^350)` or `func 25`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't. Like most programming languages, Haskell conceptually passes arguments to functions by value†, not by expression form. An `Integer` is just a [GMP](https://gmplib.org/) bignum—a bunch of bits representing the integer in a binary encoding‡. When you pass one to a function, it has absolutely no way to know where it came from or how it was constructed. What you *can* do is inspect it and decide whether it's too large to want to display.

```
funkyfunk a
  | a > 10^(30 :: Int) = func1 a
  | otherwise          = func2 a
```

† Haskell actually uses a *call by need* evaluation model, but that distinction is immaterial here.

‡ Small `Integer` values are actually represented differently, but that cannot help you even if you are foolhardy enough to dig into the internal details.

Comment: ...but (at least with extant `Integer` implementations) this comparison will evaluate `a` fully.

Comment: @DanielWagner, yes, that's the idea. The "You can't" I opened with really does sum it up accurately.